# Convexity inequality

Tags: inequality, convex-optimization, vector-analysis

How can i, for a convex function such that $\nabla f$ is L-lipschitz, i.e $\|\nabla f(x) -\nabla f(y) \| \leq L\|x-y\|$, this inequality:
\begin{equation}
f(x)-f(y) \leq \langle \nabla f(x), x-y \rangle - \frac{1}{2L} \|\nabla f(x) - \nabla f(y) \|^2
\end{equation}
Thank you in advance

Comment: does Taylor's theorem help?

Comment: Not really, i've tried it but it doesn't give anything interesting.